# Regex to match to end of line with wildcard

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need to match a URL in google analytics for use in a goal and a funnel.

I would like to match a url for http://url.com/guides/anything-that-comes-after

I will be matching /guides on it's own goal, but would like to match /guides/* (how I would do it with a simple wildcard) with the regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you're trying to match anything that comes after "guides/", basically?

```
^http\:\/\/url\.com\/guides\/(.+)$
```

should match anything after your based URL. If you want to make it domain independent, try this:

```
^http\:\/\/.+?\/guides\/(.+)$
```

Comment: It appears the second one will work just great for me. Thanks.

Comment: However - now that I'm in analytics it's telling me, "if your goal URL is www.example.com/cats/prettycatcheckout.html, then the Request URI is everything after the domain name: /cats/prettycatcheckout.html" So I have used the end of that regex: \/guides\/(.+)$ to accomplish this.

Comment: That works too in this case, but just be careful when being non-specific with regexes - if you know that x must follow y must follow z, only checking if y follows z can be dangerous if you need your parsed data to be precise.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
.*?/guides/(.*)
```